pandas dataframe to Bigquery via API
I am no longer able to write a dataframe to big query. Previously this was working.
Using google-cloud-bigquery 3.22.0
Using google-cloud 0.34.0
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery
import numpy as np

def authenticate():
    creds, projects = google.auth.default()
    project = 'project'  # Project ID inserted based on the query results selected to explore
    location = 'US'  # Location inserted based on the query results selected to explore
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project, location=location)
    return client

def update_table(table_id, data, client):
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE")

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        data, table_id, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
    return job.result()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),
              columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df)
table = ['table_name']
client = authenticate()
xx = update_table(table, df, client)

I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\df_testing.py", line 31, in <module>
    xx = update_table(table, df, client)
  File ".\df_testing.py", line 21, in update_table
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
  File ".\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 2824, in load_table_from_dataframe
    return self.load_table_from_file(
  File ".\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 2570, in load_table_from_file
    load_job = job.LoadJob(job_ref, None, destination, self, new_job_config)
  File ".\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\job\load.py", line 639, in __init__
    destination.to_api_repr(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'


Ah found it.
Previously I was updating several tables so iterating over a list.
Having
['table_name']

And not iterating over it was the problem.
